# How to map two collections in mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have doubt how to map two collection in mongodb using mongoclient.I tried it but its not working.how to solve it

**group_promotion** collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf7679a0b0bed2e7483b998"), 
    "group_name" : "Latest", 
    "products" : [ObjectId("5cecc161e8c1e73478956333"),ObjectId("5cecc161e8c1e73478956334")]  
}
```

**product** collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cecc161e8c1e73478956333"), 
    "product_name" : "bourbon"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cecc161e8c1e73478956334"), 
    "product_name" : "bour"
}
```

Expected output:

```
{   
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf7679a0b0bed2e7483b998"),   
    "group_name" : "Latest",   
    "products" : [{   
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cecc161e8c1e73478956333"),   
    "product_name" : "bourbon"  
    },{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5cecc161e8c1e73478956334"),   
    "product_name" : "bour"  
   }]    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) directly on `products` array to get expected result:

```
db.group_promotion.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "product",
            localField: "products",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "products"
        }
    }
])
```

This will take `products` from an array, find corresponding documents in `products` collection an overwrite exisiting `products` array in `group_production`

Comment: @micki but I have another doubt this scenario can you please see group promotional collection and product collection.

Comment: @HariSmith have you opened another question ?

Comment: @micki no I have changed my question can you please see for group promotional collection and product collection this scenario how to acheive mapping two collections

Comment: @micki sorry I wrong edit data .I will correct and updated it.can you please tell me this scenerio how to achieve it.

Comment: @HariSmith just try the same query, it should work work one to many relationship as well

Comment: @micki ok thanks for u comment .I wll tried it

Comment: @micki thanks for your solution this its working fine.